# How to download rtmp video stream on linux?

Tags: debian, video, rtmp

I want to download a video recorded today at 5-6 pm from the following earthcam:

```
http://www.abbeyroad.com/crossing
```

How can i download it in debian or ubuntu?

Inspecting the source code i got the following:

```
rtmp://video4.earthcam.com/archives/MP4:abbeyroad_archives/2016/03/26/1700.mp4
```

I tried using the rtmpdump application as follow:

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://video4.earthcam.com/archives/MP4:abbeyroad_archives/2016/03/26/1700.mp4"
```

but i get the following error message

> INFO: Connected... ERROR: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound

Comment: Ugh, for me, the problem was just that the RTMP URL had changed from a couple minutes ago on cloudfront.net.

Comment: `rtmpdump -r rtmp://.../mp4:mp4/.../01.mp4 -y mp4:mp4/.../01.mp4 -o test.mp4 -v` worked! Mine gets stuck if `-v` isn’t provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying playpath `-y`, like this:

```
$ rtmpdump -r rtmp://video4.earthcam.com/archives/MP4:abbeyroad_archives/2016/03/26/1700.mp4 -y MP4:abbeyroad_archives/2016/03/26/1700.mp4 -o ~/2016-03-26_1700.mp4
```

### Explanation

Regarding the error `NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound`, ["NhJm" at mplayerhq.hu](https://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/rtmpdump/2012-April/001932.html) wrote:

> rtmpdump wasn't able to figure out the app/playpath on its own, so you need
>       to tell it what they are:

- "NhJm"'s full solution used both specifying app, playpath.
- However, for your needs, it seems to work simply by specifying playpath: `-y MP4:abbeyroad_archives/2016/03/26/1700.mp4`

[`man rtmp`](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/rtmpdump.1.html):

> --playpath     -y path
>
> Overrides  the  playpath  parsed  from the RTMP URL. Sometimes the rtmpdump URL parser cannot determine the correct playpath automatically, so it must be given explicitly using this option.

Additional options:

- `-o ~/2016-03-26_1700.mp4` to save to `~/2016-03-26_1700.mp4`, you can customize this output path to your liking

For my test, I merely tested if it could start and then canceled shortly after via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>:

```
...
INFO:   displayHeight         450.00
INFO:   moovposition          115974321.00
INFO:   duration              3604.94
2035.687 kB / 26.59 sec (0.7%)^C
Caught signal: 2, cleaning up, just a second...
ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet body. len: 1024
2037.111 kB / 26.66 sec (0.7%)
Download may be incomplete (downloaded about 0.70%), try resuming
```

Resulting file from my test, although only about `0.7%`, has about 30s playable video when tested with mplayer2. So if you don't cancel or if you canceled, you could resume via the `-e` option, you can get the full video.

So now you can successfully observe Beatles [Abbey Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbey_Road) imitators via rtmp.

### Further Reading

- [NhJm's mplayerhq.hu solution](https://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/rtmpdump/2012-April/001932.html)
- [Online copy of RTMPDUMP manual](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/rtmpdump.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rtmpdump -r rtmp://video4.earthcam.com/archives/ -y MP4:abbeyroad_archives/2016/03/26/1700.mp4 -o 1700.mp4
```

If it's a stream you'll need to add the `-v` option.